# error while using state and map in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

> I am new to react. I am fetching github user info on search. I unable
>   to fetch data in my child component. this is my code below.
>   whats the problem , cant i use this.state.userList.map

```
class SearchHeader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errorMessage: '',
            userList: [],
            isOpen: false,
            userName:''

        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this);
    }
    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }
    // componentWillMount(){
    //     this.getUsers();
    //   }

      getUsers(e) {
        console.log('get users called='+e.target.value);
        fetch('https://api.github.com/search/users?q='+ e.target.value)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            userList =>{
                this.setState({userList: userList})
                console.log(userList);
            }
        );
      }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary  navbar-inner">
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-inner navb" >

                        <ul className="navbar-nav  bg-light mr-auto">

                            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle auto" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Sort
                               </a>
                                <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Sort by Name (ascending)</a>
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Sort by Name (descending)</a>
                                    <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Sort by Rank (ascending)</a>
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Sort by Rank (descending)</a>                                                                 
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 auto" onSubmit={this.getUsers}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="Search" placeholder="Search" 
                                aria-label="Search"  
                                id="userName"                                 
                                onKeyUp={this.getUsers} >                 
                                </input>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div > 

                    <UserList userList={this.state.userList}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchHeader;
```

> This is my child component below where I am fetching data from parent
>   component
>   This is my child component below where I am fetching data from parent
>   component

```
class UserList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      this.state ={
          users:this.props.userList
      }
    }




    render() {

        return (

            <div className="container-fluid">
                <br />
                {
                    this.state.users.map((user)=>
                    <div className="jumbotron container">
                   {user.login}
                  </div>
                )

                }
            </div>



        );
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: try `this.props.users.map` in child component.

Comment: What *specific* error message do you get

Comment: Try `this.props.userList` or `this.state.users` in child component

Comment: Is this correct approach    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      this.state ={
          users:this.props.userList
      }
    }

Comment: You dont need a state inside UserList component. Try map over props.users. It should work. Also if it dosent please update the question with the error message.

Comment: this.props.userList is not a function

Comment: I removed state is UserList component and used this.props.userList.map   , I am getting TypeError: this.props.userList.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your components:

- do not copy parent's state into chilren states: `users:this.props.userList`. Use `this.props` directly instead and React will know it must re-render children
- do not rely on current state to set new state. Use function with `prevState` instead of `isOpen: !this.state.isOpen`.
- make a copy of event's value before passing it to `setState` like this `const {value} = e.target;`
- assign **unique key** to each user in your list (not indexes!), or it won't re-render correctly on list update

So your code would look like this:

```
class SearchHeader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errorMessage: '',
            userList: [],
            isOpen: false,
            userName:''

        };
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState( (prevState) => ({
            isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
        }));
    }

    getUsers = (e) => {
        const {value} = e.target;
        console.log('get users called='+value);
        fetch('https://api.github.com/search/users?q='+ value)
        ...
    }

}
```

and:

```
class UserList extends Component {
    // Use default constructor

    render() {
        const users = this.props.userList.map( (user) => (
            <div className="jumbotron container" key={user.login}>
              {user.login}
            </div>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <br />
              {users}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: this.props.userList.map is not a function for this code in UserList component

Comment: What does `console.log(userList);` display?

Comment: Object { total_count: 272740, incomplete_results: false, items: Array[30] }  in console

Comment: Then you should replace `this.setState({userList: userList})` by `this.setState({userList: userList.items})`

Comment: after this setState changes how should UserList should look now

Answer (score 0):

> parent component change should be.

```
getUsers(e) {
        console.log('get users called='+e.target.value);
        fetch('https://api.github.com/search/users?q='+ e.target.value)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            userList =>{
                this.setState({userList: userList.items})
                console.log(userList);
            }
        );
      }
```

> Change your user list and check initially values are there or not and you dont need to user state in userList component.
>   that is all because initially there are no values also there can be an case when you are setting state for userList value after fetching data that might be coming as null undefined or something else so put an console log there and check that too.

class UserList extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                
                    
                    {
                        this.props.userList && this.props.userList.length && this.props.userList.map((user)=>
                        
                       {user.login}
                      
                    )

```
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserList;
```